# Google Dialogflow CX - phone number is spoke back as a integer, not individual numbers

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm fairly new at Dialogflow CX and have used the system entity sys.phon-number to capture user input for phone number, then  I play it back to the user via phone call in the session.parms.sys.phone-number variable.

The problem is the bot is speaking the number as 8 billion, 1 hundred thousand etc.. not reading it back , i.e 8 0 1

I explored adding to the sys entity using expressions, but that  doesn't  seem to  be working. Not even sure I'm doing it correctly. Any  guides out there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to SSML tag speak and before phone number use tag say-as interpret-as="telephone" , It will work